# Trouble passing multiple html values through a php loop

Tags: php, html, xml

I am working on an assignment that requires me to send the song title and song length to another php file and then save the values to a database. The index page outputs all the different song titles and song lengths with buttons to click on each. When I click one of the buttons it correctly sends the value for the length but it sends the last value in the loop for the title. Please help!

```html
<form action="insertFavorite.php" method="post">
<div class="container">
    <!-- Top Navigation -->
    <div class="component">
        <table>

            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo "Song Name"; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo "Duration"; ?></th>
            </tr>

            <?php foreach($album->song as $songs){
                echo '<tr><td>'.$songs["title"]."</td><td>" .$songs["length"]."</td> <td>".'<input length="30" width="30" type="image" src="add.png" name="length" alt="submit" value="'.$songs["length"].'">'."</td> <td>".'<input type="hidden" name="title" alt="submit" value="'.$songs["title"].'">'.'</td> </tr>';}?>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>

        </table>

    </div><!-- /container -->
    </form>
```

Comment: because you will have X number of  hidden inputs with the same name

Comment: but so does the first input with the name "length" and it sends the correct variable that is clicked

Comment: because its the button clicked on

Comment: so how would I go about sending both of the values because you can only have one value per input

Comment: deliminated then split perhaps

Answer (score 0):

Though there might be a lot of songs, you are only submitting one at a time. Then you can create a lot of forms by adding the form tag as well in the loop. Like this -

```
            <?php 
            foreach($album->song as $songs){
                echo '<form action="insertFavorite.php" method="post">';
                echo '<tr><td>'.$songs["title"]."</td><td>" .$songs["length"]."</td> <td>".'<input length="30" width="30" type="image" src="add.png" name="length" alt="submit" value="'.$songs["length"].'">'."</td> <td>".'<input type="hidden" name="title" alt="submit" value="'.$songs["title"].'">'.'</td> </tr>';
                echo '</form>';
            }
        ?>
```

Or you can have checkboxes along with songs to add more than one at a time.

```
            <?php 
            echo '<form action="insertFavorite.php" method="post">';
            foreach($album->song as $songs){                    
                echo '<tr><td>'.$songs["title"]."</td><td>" .$songs["length"]."</td> <td>".'<input type="checkbox"  name="song_length[]" alt="song length" value="'.$songs["length"].'">'."</td> <td>".'<input type="hidden" name="song_title[]" alt="submit" value="'.$songs["title"].'">'.'</td> </tr>';                    
            }
            echo '<input length="30" width="30" type="image" src="add.png" alt="submit" >';
            echo '</form>';                
        ?>
```

This will give you array of song titles as well as their lengths.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is that you are sending multiple fields but only the last one is received in the database. 
When submitting multiple fields of the same field name, it is best if you use array for the name 
In your your code, add an array notation on the name property of the field:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="title[]" alt="submit" value="'.$songs["title"].'">'.'</td> </tr>';}?>
```

Then as you submit this, on your back-end PHP script, this will be fetched as an array. The thing is though you will have to move your submit/save button outside of the loop and all of the data will be sent every time you submit.

Another solution for this instead is to use AJAX instead. As the user clicks on the button, you will send a POST message using the fields relative to the button.
For example: let's say we use normal buttons instead

(By the way instead of using echo why not exclude the html elements your PHP script

```
<tr><td> <?= $songs["title"] ?></td><td> <?=$songs["length"] ?></td> <td> 
    <img length="30" width="30" src="add.png" name="length" alt="SAVE" value="<?=$songs["length"] ?>">
    </td> <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="title" alt="submit" value="<?=$songs["title"] ?>"> </td>
</tr>
```

Here we replace the imagebutton with an ordinary submit. Now we can see that under the same TR, we will use JQuery to traverse the relative fields

```
$(".add").click(function(){
     var title = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name=title]").val();

     //insert your AJAX code here
});
```